# How to solve a simple linear problem with clp-java

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming

I want to solve this problem using [clp-java](https://github.com/quantego/clp-java)

```
Maximize 2 * x + 5 where x <= 10
```

I use this code

```
CLP clp = new CLP();
CLPVariable x = clp.addVariable().free();
clp.createExpression().add(2, x).add(5).asObjective();
clp.createExpression().add(x).leq(10);
clp.maximize();

System.out.println("obj=" + clp.getObjectiveValue());
System.out.println("x=" + x.getSolution());
```

that produces this output

```
obj=15.0
x=10.0
```

My question is why the objective value is 15 and not 25 as it should be?

Comment: Can't reproduce with the newest version v1.16.11 downloaded from github. The output is correctly `obj=25.0`.

Comment: Thank you @Turamarth. Indeed the v1.16.11 produces a correct result. I was using v1.16.10. But I have another issue that I cannot resolve v1.16.11 from the maven repository. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is fixed in the newest version v1.16.11.
To include this version using maven you need to add the following dependency to your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.quantego</groupId>
    <artifactId>clp-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.11</version>
</dependency>
```

They changed the groupID between the versions.

According to [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.quantego/clp-java/1.16.11) the artifact should be included in the [Mulesoft](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/quantego/clp-java/1.16.11) repository but I can't find it there.
You might be out of luck if you can't find it somewhere else.

Comment: I am getting "Cannot resolve com.github.quantego:clp-java:1.16.11"

Comment: @Oscar Broman I rolled back your edit since according to mvnrepository.com the version without v is the newest one. Either way it doesn't change the fact that the artifact is not available as far as I can see.

Comment: @Turamarth I noticed that but was unable to undo my edit because it was pending review.